# how to raise customized error in mongodb using javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I want to raise a customize error along with its error code in mongodb using javascript.

Here is what I have tried :

Basically, I have executed java script by passing it as CLI argument to mongo client as follows :

## `mongo ipaddress:port/test --file.js`

For test purpose, my file.js file contains single line as "throw 144" but when I execute above command and do a echo $? it gives me other error code then 144.

Please let me know how I can do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`quit()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/reference/method/quit/) function.

```
quit(144);
```